# Lint does not find an Activity from a Library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

I have a library project (in ADT) containing an Activity.

This library is used by a project that uses this Activity.

All this works perfectly well. The Activity is declared in the main project's manifest, it compiles, it runs, it does everything I need.

All the compilation, library linking, lint checking happens in stock ADT without the help of anything else. (no maven, no ant, no makefile)

However, when I run lint on the project, it complains that

> Class referenced in the manifest, com.test.library.LibraryActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries

Which is incorrect, since it compiles and run.

I have cleaned, removed the lint markers, deleted the lint.xml file, restarted ADT, still the same issue.

I would like to have a proper full lint check before releasing. Any idea?

### Edit

I have been doing more testing, and apparently command line `lint MyProject` works, tests library correctly

Answer (score 2):

Here is the lint bug:

[listed as an issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40005)

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I didn't find this bug report.

Comment: I don't understand if the claimed fix release is in lint only, or in the integration with the IDE, though.

Answer (score 0):

An easy work around is to created an activity that inherits from the one in the library and referencing this activity in your manifest.

Comment: yes, possibly, but I really don't want to do stuff like that just to please lint. Also, in command line it works.